# Bash script to (more or less) reliably check if the Internet is up

Tags: linux, shell, internet-connection

I need a Bash (or a plain shell) script to put in a cronjob that every minute checks if the Internet is up.

This is how I did it:

```
#! /bin/sh

host1=google.com
host2=wikipedia.org
curr_date=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`

echo -n "${curr_date};"
((ping -w5 -c3 $host1 || ping -w5 -c3 $host2) > /dev/null 2>&1) && 
echo "up" || (echo "down" && exit 1)
```

How would you do it? Which hosts would you ping?

**Clarifications:**

- By "*internet is up*", I mean **my** internet connection.
- By "*up*", I mean to have usable connection (doesn't really matter if we are talking about the DNS being  down or the connection is really really slow [mind the `-w` for timeout]). That is also why I didn't include any IP but only hosts.

Should I also ping Stack Overflow? I mean, if I can't access Google, Wikipedia or Stack Overflow, I don't want Internet :p

Comment: Google is what I always use to test if I've got a connection.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 would be good as well, especially since it's multicast.

Comment: The Internet as a whole is generally "up". However, your connection to it may not be! ;-)

Comment: @John when I said internet is up i meant my connection is up, but you made a good point. :) If I wanted to know if the Internet is up I would have just pinged google ;)

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is not Bash (even if `sh` is symlinked to `bash`).

Comment: ups... I was going to do a `bash` script and then noticed that I could just do `sh` (which is usually more compatible) and forgot to put the right tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That one seems like a good solution. Just add a few more hosts, and maybe some pure IP hosts so you don't rely on DNS functioning (which in itself depends on your definition of "up").

Comment: Actually depending on DNS functioning might be a good thing. If you want to check actual "I can browse the web like normal"-operation, then requiring DNS support is A Good Thing(TM).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your code, it works great, I've left only one line actually:

```
((ping -w5 -c3 8.8.8.8 || ping -w5 -c3 4.2.2.1) > /dev/null 2>&1) && echo "up" || (echo "down" && exit 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What portion of Internet connectivity are you looking to check? DHCP? DNS? Physically being plugged into a jack? Kernel recognizing the presence of the NIC?

You can manually query your ISP's DNS server(s) by using the `host(1)` command. This is generally a good indication of whether your router has lost its connection to the ISP.

You can query what interfaces your kernel has by using `netstat(8)` or `ifconfig(8)`.

You can get detailed statistics about the interface using `ifstat`.